# with jQuery modify CSS .on mouseenter: for a specific ul li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to jQuery and can't quite figure out how to achieve what I'm trying to do. Server can work only with HTML - no PHP or Ruby available (that and I'm not familiar with those languages yet). I'm also using the latest jQuery 1.10.2

What I have is a menu with tiles that each have a preview picture and a title ribbon (the  to be specific), what I want is for the titles ribon background to change the opacity when mouse cursor hovers over tile.

So far I have it so that it sort of works, but the problem is that whenever a mouse cursor hovers over a tile, all the titles change the opacity, and not just the one being hovered over. I tried to get index number of a 'li' element using .index and then return it to be used as a identifier, but that didn't quite work. I also tried to do something like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('menu ul li').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this) <some code would come here to do stuff as mouse cursor enters the item area> ;
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this) <some code would come here to undo stuff as mouse cursor leaves the item area>;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But I couldn't figure out how to continue off of that to modify the `$('.tt1').css`

So here's the relevant code fragments of what I have so far...

jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('menu ul li').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $('.tt1').css('opacity', '1.0');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $('.tt1').css('opacity', '0.6');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The HTML code:

```
<menu>
    <ul class="collumn-left">
        <li><a href="#About"><div class="tt1">About</div></a></li>
        <li><a href="#Test"><div class="tt1">Test</div></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="collumn-right">
        <li><a href="#Random"><div class="tt1">Random</div></a></li>
        <li><a href="#More"><div class="tt1">More</div></a></li>
    </ul>
</menu>
```

The CSS code:

```
/*  menu section begin */
menu {
    background-color: silver;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #6A6A6A;
}
menu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
.collumn-left,
.collumn-right {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
.collumn-left a,
.collumn-right a {
    float: left;
    border: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tt1 {
    background-color: grey;
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
}
.tt1:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
/*  menu section end */

/*  Medium display size - Tablet devices & Desktops/Laptops */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
    menu {
        min-width: 370px;
        width: 1024px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #6A6A6A;
    }
    .collumn-left,
    .collumn-right {
        width: 512px;
    }
    .collumn-left a,
    .collumn-right a {
        width: 502px;
        height: 502px;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .tt1 {
        margin: 325px 0 102px 0;
        font-size: 35px;
        line-height: 75px;
    }
    article {
        margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
    }
}

/*  High Display Resolution Desktops/Laptops */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1281px) {
    menu {
        min-width: 370px;
        width: 1540px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #6A6A6A;
    }
    .collumn-left,
    .collumn-right {
        width: 770px;
    }
    .collumn-left a,
    .collumn-right a {
        width: 760px;
        height: 760px;
        margin: 5px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .tt1 {
        margin: 500px 0 160px 0;
        font-size: 40px;
        line-height: 100px;
    }
    article {
        margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You were on the right track with your first JS block. In the second, you lost specificity and applied your change to *all* .tt1 elements.

Comment: Yea, that's what I had a hunch of how it should work, I just couldn't figure out how to continue from there and didn't know how to actually get it to work as I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('menu ul li').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).find(".tt1").css('opacity', '1.0');
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).find(".tt1").css('opacity', '0.6');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

edit:

Another, maybe more cleaner way to achieve this would be the following:

CSS

```
.tt1:hover, .tt1.hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('menu ul li').on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).find(".tt1").addClass("hover");
            },
            mouseleave: function () {
                $(this).find(".tt1").removeClass("hover");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You could easily add other features by just editing your css. For example a nice transition or different styles for smaller screens.

Comment: Thanks, that works out just in the way I was looking for. I saw the '.find' in the jQuery API reference, but didn't even try it because I thought that it would do just the same what my code was doing - find all the ".tt1" divs and change opacity for all of them.

Comment: I actually have the site created to respond to different screen sizes(including smaller resolutions), I simply kept the code relevant and included only the part that I was having difficulty with.

Comment: Yeah, you've added your `@media`-queries - that's why I've edited my answer ;)

Comment: Yeah, I added those in case someone didn't quite get what I'm going for and might want to replicate it.

Answer (score 2):

No need for javascript just use css

```
menu ul li .ttl:hover {
   opacity:1.0;
}
```

Comment: @KārlisK. if its the li hover you want to make it activate just change the selector to `menu ul li:hover .ttl`

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).find('.tt1').css('opacity', '1.0');`

`find()` will look for a child element of the hovered element with the class tt1.

Comment: or just change the `menu ul li` selector to include the `.ttl` class, then just use `$(this).`

Comment: "jack" and "vic3685" got answer I was trying to achieve. Changing ' menu ul li ' to ' menu ul li .tt1 ' would only change the title ribbons opacity only when a mouse pointer/cursor would hover over it but would not do so when the tile itself would be hovered over.